# Restore Magento Color Attribute

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes

I have accidentally deleted the "color" attribute with the `->delete();` function.

Would anyone know what entries and in what tables need to be restored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simpler way to do is create a new attribute from Magento admin (see below screenshot for reference)

[image: see attached screenshot for reference]

or if you need data to be restored as well then you need to go into your db backup and get it from there.

Hope it helps

Cheers
S

Comment: No worries, I am glad I could help!